# App Icon Launch

Tags: android

Quick question I'm trying to change my app's launch icon but it doesn't seem to want to change. I changed the dimensions of it to the following for the variety of screen sizes as seen here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

- 36 x 36 for ldpi
- 48 x 48 for mdpi
- 72 x 72 for hdpi

Plus in the android manifest file I added the following line:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/iss" android:label="Endeavor">
```

Yet when I run the app and look for it on the phone it's basic launch icon is the default android green icon. What's the problem here?

Comment: check iss is you android default icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstall app and reinstall.... Sometimes the icon does not update :s

Comment: You are correct sir! After un-installing the app and re-installing it the logo loads. Funny thing is that when I selected the app to un-install it the logo was there...

Answer (score 1):

The three icons (for different dimensions) need to be saved respectively as

```
drawable-ldpi/iss.png
drawable-mdpi/iss.png
drawable-hdpi/iss.png
```

Then with your manifest they should be picked up.  Also, I suggest you move your "Endeavor" value of `android:label` to your string resources file (usually strings.xml) and change the value here to refer to it.  It'll save you a lot of pain later - trust me.

Comment: Yeh I understand that point - shortly after I posted I changed it to @string/app_name for ease later. Cheers